Concerned About Indemification Clause
looking to accept a new contract to work on a software development  project, but I'm concerned about this Indemnification Clause:

“Contractor agrees to indemnify, defend, and hold harmless Company
from and against any and all claims, damages, losses, liabilities,
costs, and expenses (including reasonable attorneys' fees) arising out
of or in connection with a third party claim, action, or proceeding,
based directly or indirectly on any breach of its warranties contained
herein or arising from or relation to its performance under this
agreement.”

My Employer said that this means:

“ In the event of a lawsuit resulting from the creation or
implementation of this project, that you would be on the side of
Company — that you would not blame Company if anything went wrong..."

But From what I can tell, I’m not sure if this is really the case, the clause seems to say that  I need to pay for  any claims  damages losses liabilities cost and expenses including attorney fees  that come from our any connection to  third party claims actions or proceedings, potentially past the amount I'm being paid for. Moreover, this seems to indicate that I will have unlimited liability as, while there is a termination clause, there is no limit of liability clause.
So  to wrap up, which interpretation of the clause is more accurate to the meaning of the clause? And If it matches up with my interpretation and concerns for unlimited liability, how can I alter it to better protect myself and to make it more fair?

As an innocent bystander, it sounds to me that your interpretation is correct... sadly.

Are you doing the work as a contractor or an employee? I probably can't give an answer either way, but I think it makes a big difference in the analysis. What jurisdiction is this in?

Like a professional like a doctor, lawyer, architect, or even travel agent, you need to talk to a licensed insurance agent and buy appropriate professional liability insurance.

@GerardAshton Im a contractor, not an employee

Mr. employer's characterization of the agreement is well off the mark; your restatement is more or less correct.
